# How to remove commas from columns of pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have an excel data for population of Indian states. The columns are object datatype but i want to convert into integer datatype. Columns have commas and i want to remove those commas but the problem is when i am trying remove them the cells getting null values.
I have imported relevant python packages to read the excel files and work on it such as pandas and numpy.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df=pd.read_excel("https://github.com/gambler2020/Data/blob/main/indian%20state%20population.xlsx?raw=true")
```

below code will display the types of each column.

```
df.dtypes
output:
States    object
2011      object
2023      object
dtype: object
```

df.head(5) is used to print top 5 records from the dataset. and here it can be seen there are several commas involve in the cells of column.

```
    States              2011            2023
0   Uttar Pradesh       19,98,12,341    2,35,687,000
1   Maharashtra         11,23,74,333    1,26,385,000
2   Bihar               10,40,99,452    1,26,756,000
3   West Bengal         9,12,76,115     99084000
4   Madhya Pradesh      7,26,26,809     86579000
```

Here i have tried to replace those commas with nothing so that i could convert these columns to integer types.

```
df[2011]=df[2011].str.replace(",", "")
df[2023]=df[2023].str.replace(",", "")
```

df.head(10) from the above code, i was expecting to have normal column but unfortunately i got several cells that have null value.

```
    States          2011        2023
0   Uttar Pradesh   199812341   235687000
1   Maharashtra     112374333   126385000
2   Bihar           104099452   126756000
3   West Bengal     91276115    NaN
4   Madhya Pradesh  72626809    NaN
5   Tamil Nadu      72147030    NaN
6   Rajasthan       68548437    NaN
7   Karnataka       61095297    NaN
8   Gujarat         60439692    NaN
9   Andhra Pradesh  NaN         NaN
```

i am expecting to have all column integer datatype except the states column.

Comment: it is same as object datatypes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
df[[2011, 2023]] = df[[2011, 2023]].replace(',', '', regex=True).astype(int)
print(df)

# Output
                                  States       2011       2023
0                          Uttar Pradesh  199812341  235687000
1                            Maharashtra  112374333  126385000
2                                  Bihar  104099452  126756000
3                            West Bengal   91276115   99084000
4                         Madhya Pradesh   72626809   86579000
5                             Tamil Nadu   72147030   76860000
...
30                            Chandigarh    1055450    1231000
31                                Sikkim     610577     689000
32  Dadra & Nagar Haveli and Daman & Diu     586956    1263000
33                     Andaman & Nicobar     380581     403000
34                                Ladakh     274289     300000
35                           Lakshadweep      64473      69000
```

You got NaN because for right formatted numbers, the type is `int` and use the `str.replace` method will give you nan values for real integers:

```
>>> df.loc[35, 2011]
64473

>>> type(df.loc[35, 2011])  # str.replace can't work in this case
int

>>> df.loc[0, 2011]
'19,98,12,341'

>>> type(df.loc[0, 2011])
str
```

If you want to `str.replace` works, you have to force the column dtype:

```
>>> df[2011].astype(str).str.replace(',', '')
0     199812341
1     112374333
2     104099452
3      91276115
4      72626809
5      72147030
...
30      1055450
31       610577
32       586956
33       380581
34       274289
35        64473
Name: 2011, dtype: object
```

Comment: can you tell me what was problem in my code?

Comment: I updated my answer to explain the problem. Does it clear now?

Answer (score 1):

The `2023` column is dtype `object`, but if you look at the individual cell values, you find them to be a mix of `str` and `int`. Pandas converted what it could to its most matching type.

```
>>> set(type(cell) for cell in df[2023])
{<class 'int'>, <class 'str'>}
```

You can change the type to string and then do the replace.

```
df[2023]=df[2023].astype(str).str.replace(",", "")
```

Comment: I explained the same thing as you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Also, try `thousands` parameter.

```
df=pd.read_excel("https://github.com/gambler2020/Data/blob/main/indian%20state%20population.xlsx?raw=true", thousands=',')

df.info()
```

Output:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 36 entries, 0 to 35
Data columns (total 3 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------  --------------  ----- 
 0   States  36 non-null     object
 1   2011    36 non-null     int64 
 2   2023    36 non-null     int64 
dtypes: int64(2), object(1)
memory usage: 992.0+ bytes
```

And, `df.head()`:

```
           States       2011       2023
0   Uttar Pradesh  199812341  235687000
1     Maharashtra  112374333  126385000
2           Bihar  104099452  126756000
3     West Bengal   91276115   99084000
4  Madhya Pradesh   72626809   86579000
```